# how to save hindi text in JSON

Tags: php, mysql, utf

I have some text in hindi.

Is it possible to save that text in json file. (.json)

I will save this on S3 and later render it inside my Ionic2 app.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: The JSON standard demands the JSON text to be in Unicode and therefore any proper encoder/decoder can deal with any valid Unicode characters (that would include Hindi text)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. Simply use `json_encode($a, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` to prevent escaping Unicode characters.
For more information you can see the documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php