# json doesnt show hindi text

Tags: android, json, utf-8, hindi

I have the following User classin my android app

```
public class User {

@SerializedName("activity_name")
@Expose
private String activityName;
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("image_url")
@Expose
private String imageUrl;
@SerializedName("album_name_hindi")
@Expose
private String albumNameHindi;
@SerializedName("album_name_english")
@Expose
private String albumNameEnglish;

public String getActivityName() {
    return activityName;
}

public void setActivityName(String activityName) {
    this.activityName = activityName;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public String getAlbumNameHindi() {
    return albumNameHindi;
}

public void setAlbumNameHindi(String albumNameHindi) {
    this.albumNameHindi = albumNameHindi;
}

public String getAlbumNameEnglish() {
    return albumNameEnglish;
}

public void setAlbumNameEnglish(String albumNameEnglish) {
    this.albumNameEnglish = albumNameEnglish;
}

}
```

the following is my json code (shortened for the sake of SO)

```
[
 {
  "activity_name":"Dhamma Jaagran",
  "id":1,
  "image_url":"http://humipack.in/Dj/album01.webp",
  "album_name_hindi":"मंगल स्तुति",
  "album_name_english":"Mangal Stuti"
 },
 {
  "activity_name":"Dhamma Jaagran",
  "id":2,
  "image_url":"http://humipack.in/Dj/album2.webp",
  "album_name_hindi":"भिक्षु स्तुति",
  "album_name_english":"Bhikshu Stuti"
 }
]
```

The problem i face is i am unable to get the HINDI text properly.. I have saved the Json in UTF-8 format..

I am getting the output for **मंगल स्तुति** as some random characters mostly seen in Character Map in Windows..  but not in hindi.. 
Is there any line of code i am missing , for e.g  to convert HINDI text to Unicode or UTF-8..

I also refered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138403/how-to-save-hindi-text-in-json) but it shows how to make changes in php which i am not using..

What modification do i have to make in my code to get the HINDI in my android app data of which comes from json file..

Comment: could you add some server side code to understand the situation

Comment: the json code is already added.. @TouhidulIslam .. i have not used php in my app..

Comment: The device you're testing on might not have the correct fonts installed on it. Maybe try to embed your font in the app.

Comment: my other apps without json shows hindi perfectly .. @G-man

Comment: The JSON needs to have UTF-8 encoded strings, not unicode characters.

Comment: how to encode strings as UTF-8